# Wordpress title as keywords (tags) with excluded stop words

Tags: tags, title, get-the-title

How to change normal sentence WordPress title to "tag like" list with excluded "stop words".

Example:

"This is one test post title about something."

To:

"one, test, post, title, something"

This is my function which will exclude blacklist words (stop words), and words with less than 3 characters (usually stop words too).

```
<?php    
// Post title as keywords, excluded stop words
function title_as_keywords( $word )
{
$blacklist = array('this', 'about', 'that', 'them'); // Excluded words ...
    if ( !in_array( $word, $blacklist ) && strlen( $word ) > 3 ) { //Exclude words with less than 4 characters
          $word_with_comma = '' .$word. ', '; // Separate words with comma
          return $word_with_comma;
      }
    else { return ''; } // Return nothing for black list words or words with less than 4 characters

}
?>

<?php
$title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); // Get title
$parts = explode( ' ', $title );
echo title_as_keywords( $parts[0] );
echo title_as_keywords( $parts[1] );
echo title_as_keywords( $parts[2] );
echo title_as_keywords( $parts[3] );
//...
?>
```

**Problems:**
This is working fine but it needs fine tuning. This will give this result:

"test, post, title, something, "

**Problem 1:**

I would like to display last word without ", " at the end.

**Problem 2:**

It will exclude word "one" (because it is 3 characters long), I can set it to include words with 3 characters, but than I will have to create long blacklist to include 3 characters stop words (the, who, she, are, his, her...).

Comment: You could loop through your $parts with a foreach and then trim the last character of your string that will be a ",". You could also create a second array of whitelisted <= 3 characters words.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea, to create whitelisted words, for example (red, man, boy...). Also I tried to trim ", " in last $part, but I probably made some mistake or something was wrong in my logic. Could you please update my function with added white list and with last word without ", " so I can see that? Thank you  @Antoine Guillien

Comment: Voted to migrate to [so] as this is a generic php issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated function solving your 2 problems :

```
// Post title as keywords, excluded stop words
function title_as_keywords( $word )
{
    $blacklist = array('this', 'about', 'that', 'them'); // Excluded words ...
    $whitelist = array('one', 'man', 'boy'/*etc..*/); // Whitelisted words ...
    if ( (!in_array( $word, $blacklist ) && strlen( $word ) > 3 ) || in_array($word, $whitelist)) { //Exclude words with less than 4 characters
          $word_with_comma = '' .$word. ', '; // Separate words with comma
          return $word_with_comma;
      }
    else { return ''; } // Return nothing for black list words or words with less than 4 characters

}
$title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); // Get title
$parts = explode( ' ', $title );
$str = '';
foreach ($parts as $word) {
    $str.= title_as_keywords($word);
}
$str = substr($str, 0,-2);
echo $str;
```

Hope it'll help :)